# idomenu not working in Javascript mode

Tags: javascript, emacs

My javascript code looks something like this:

```
cs.client.startApplication = function() {

  function attachStepHandler() {
    var stepNodes = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('step');

    function selectActiveElement(element) {
         ...
```

I would like to use idomenu to select the functions, but there is no selection available. So far I'm using idomenu with elisp, clojure and ruby mode without problems.

Should idomenu work with the javascript mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood `idomenu` uses the same functions for building the function list to present as `imenu` itself does. For me `imenu` doesn't work too well for JavaScript (`js-mode`) either, which is why I've rolled my own `imenu--generic-function` function like this:

```el
(defun mo-js-imenu-make-index ()
  (save-excursion
    (imenu--generic-function '((nil "function\\s-+\\([^ ]+\\)(" 1)
                               (nil "\\.\\([^\\. ]+\\)\\s-*=\\s-*function\\s-*(" 1)))))

(defun mo-js-mode-hook ()
  (setq imenu-create-index-function 'mo-js-imenu-make-index)
  (define-key js-mode-map [?\M-i] 'imenu))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'mo-js-mode-hook)
```

This well let `imenu` and hopefully by extension `idomenu` recognize both types of function definitions, the non-object-oriented one `function someFunc() {…}` and the object-oriented one as `cls.someFunc = function() {…}`.

If you want to learn more about how this works then read up on `imenu--generic-function` in Emacs' help.